# problem with adjustwidth and image

Tags: graphics, floats, margins, adjustwidth

I want to put my figure to the left of the page without using \newgeometry package. I have found on the internet some solutions, but it seems that they did not work for me.
[image: here is my figure with the code of udjustwidth]

I have also put in the preamble the correct command in order to use the adjsutwidth, but nothing happen.
I try to remove the '*' but it did not solve the problem.

[image: here the pdf produced]

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-4cm}{}

\begin{figure}[H]
\noindent \includegraphics[scale=0.4]         {Diagrams/UX/home_signUp_signIn_Discover}

\caption{Home navigation - UX.}

\end{figure}

\end{adjustwidth}
```

Here the code produced by lyx.

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind posting a minimal (non-)working full code?

Comment: why do you need any package at all other than graphics? it is hard to tell from your description but don't you just want `\hspace*{-5cm}\includegrapics{image}` ?

Comment: the problem is that i am using lyx, i try to modify the space like you but lyx give me a compilation error

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni: Why not just resize the image to the text width? Insert > Graphics > LaTeX and LyX options > LaTeX options: `width=\textwidth`

Comment: because i want the image bigger than the text i have put in the document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not put float inside "box" made by `adjustwidth`. Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{showframe}% for show page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-4cm}{}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{Diagrams/UX/home_signUp_signIn_Discover}
\caption{Home navigation - UX.}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]